# How do I merge individual files into a single sorted file?

Tags: java

I've a bunch of id's in 4 files a,b,c,d saved in my workspace. I want to merge all these id's in a sorted order in a single file merged.txt .. They will be saved one per line as a string. I could individually sort files by bringing them into memory. But how do I merge them, there can be duplicate entries. I can't think of how to compare each entry in the four files (they can grow to 8 so can't hardcode this). Particularly how do I compare the entries and how do I advance only those file pointers that are the smallest of the entries ?

```
public void sortFile() throws IOException
{
    File a = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/a.txt");
    File b = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/b.txt");
    File c = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/c.txt");
    File d = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/d.txt");

    doSort(a);
    doSort(b);
    doSort(c);
    doSort(d);

    merge();
}
```

**How do I modify the merge method according to pseudocode below ?**

```
public void merge()
{
    File dir = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data");

    for(File f: dir.listFiles())
    {
        // toDo: merge into a single file merged.txt
    }
}

public void doSort(File f) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        list.add(line);
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(f);

    for(String s:list)
    out.println(s);

    reader.close();
    out.close();
}


    public void merge() throws IOException
    {
        File dir = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data");
        File merged = new File("/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/merged.txt");

        ArrayList<BufferedReader> readers = new ArrayList<BufferedReader>(dir.listFiles().length);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(merged);

        for(File f: dir.listFiles())
        {
            readers.add(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)));
        }

        while(true)
        {
        for (BufferedReader reader: readers)
        {
            if(reader.readLine()!=null)
                list.add(reader.readLine());

            else
            {
                reader.close();
            }

        }

        String min = Collections.min(list);
        int index = list.indexOf(min);
        out.write(min);
    }



 }
```

Comment: Im confused as to the question. Do you want to know how to merge the files, how to compare them (which you seem to already do) or how do you find the smallest of the entries?

Comment: also size is very important, are these small files that you can store in an arraylist, or should these be externally sorted

Comment: They could possibly grow into very large files that might not fit in memory. Hence I m storing the entries externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general description of the algorithm:

1. Open each file, and read its first item.
2. Go through all files, and select one file with the smallest current item; if multiple files have the same item, pick the first file that has the item
3. Remove the smallest item from the file that you identified in step 2, and write it to the output file
4. If the file from which you removed the item has ended, close the file, and remove it from the list of files
5. If the list of files is not empty, go back to step 2.

Before going through with the algorithm your code needs to check that at least one input file is present; otherwise, your code should exit.

**EDIT :** Your `merge` code does not look much like the algorithm above; here is some code to help you get started:

```
// Prepare your readers and their top items
for(File f: dir.listFiles()) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String firstLine = reader.readLine();
    // Your code inserts buffered readers unconditionally;
    // You should not insert readers for empty files.
    if (firstLine != null) {
        readers.add(br);
        list.add(firstLine);
    } else {
        br.close();
    }
}
// Stop when the last reader is removed
while (!readers.isEmpty()) {
    int minIndex = ... // Find the index of the smallest item in the "list"
    out.write(list.get(minIndex));
    BufferedReader br = readers.get(minIndex);
    String next = br.readLine();
    if (next != null) {
        list.set(minIndex, next);
    } else {
        br.close();
        list.remove(minIndex);
        readers.remove(minIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems doable. Is it the most efficient way to read only one item from each file ?

Comment: @Phoenix - you misunderstood the pseudo-code.  You keep all of the files open until each one reaches the EOF.  And if you want to avoid inefficient reading and writing, you use buffered streams ... in the normal Java fashion.

Comment: Stephen, but what if I don't always know how many files I want to read from ? Hence, I am doing a dir.listFiles, how can I keep all these files open ? What does that code look like ?

Comment: @Phoenix You need a collection, such as a list, to keep your open files. The collection can grow and shrink with the number of files.

Comment: You mean a collection of bufferedReaders ?

Comment: @Phoenix You will need two collections - a collection of readers, buffered or not, and a collection of the top value that you have just read from the corresponding file. You may read on one iteration, but consume the item many iterations later, so the current item needs to be stored.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, can you help me out with the the merge code ? I have edited the post with what I tried. How do I figure out while file I need to advance ? Also, how do I modify the collection as I am traversing it since any file can be needed to close if I don't have anything left to read from it ?

Comment: @Phoenix Take a look at the update, this should be enough for you to complete the task.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to solve your problem, or solve it in Java.

If you are simply looking for ways to do this, and have access to the terminal, and by "sorting" you mean sorting alphabetically, you can do it simpler.

```
cat "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/a.txt" "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/b.txt" "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/c.txt" "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/d.txt"|sort > merged.txt
```

For sorting and only picking up the uniq ones

```
cat "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/a.txt" "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/b.txt" "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/c.txt" "/Users/phoenix/workspace/data/d.txt"|sort |uniq > merged.txt
```

Update:
BTW, to sort numerically, use

```
sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each file into a List

```
List<String> list1 = Files.readAllLines(Path.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
...
```

merge lists1 in one list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(list1);
...
```

now sort the lines

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

and write them into a single file.

Note: If you dont want duplicate lines use TreeSet instead of ArrayList

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy. It is possible that the files might grow so large that all of them might not fit in memory. Is dasblinkenlight's approach better ?

Comment: In this case I think it's better to sort each file first. But again theres no guarantee that an individual file fits in memory.